# alternating colors of spinner items

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout, spinner

Can I make the items to show up in alternating colors in spinner control

Comment: Do you mean alternating or alternative? If you mean alternative, then can you elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you are following the [Spinner Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) then you can subclass your adapter (passing a `List` of your items) to produce an alternating color effect:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList) {
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0) { // we're on an even row
            view.setBackgroundColor(evenColor);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(oddColor);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

If you're already defining your own adapter and implementing `getDropDownView` then you can add something like the above to the end of your method.

**Edit** - updated with slund's advice. Thank you!

Comment: Note that for the spinner drop down list you need to override getDropDownView.  For a Spinner getView returns the view shown in the spinner itself for the item.  getDropDownView is used to get the view to show in the list.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't actually used Spinner much, and didn't know about `getDropDownView`. I edited my answer based on your comment.

Comment: When i am trying to do what have suggested i ma getting the following error
The method getDropdowView(int, View, ViewGroup) of type new ArrayAdapter<String>(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: It's probably a spelling error. Make sure you have the method name correct.

Comment: thanks it started working but i had to put @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom adapter and change the color of each item. Look at [this](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-adapter-in-color.html) link for more details.