# Android : how to set DropDown View Resource for Spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I wrote a code for Spinner to bind array of USA States with Spinner in Android. But the problem is it shows reference type data in Spinner item, see the pic

I add `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` but not know that what to add in layout. I checked many exemples on google and they **add simple_spinner_dropdown_item** but i could not find that what to add in layout. below is output and code. I want to show states in list instead of this junky data.

[image]

```
    Spinner spStates = new Spinner(this);
        spStates.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        final USAStates states[] = new USAStates[51];

        states[0] = new USAStates("Alabama", "AL");
        states[1] = new USAStates("Alaska", "AK");
        states[2] = new USAStates("Arizona", "AZ");
ArrayAdapter<USAStates> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<USAStates>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spStates.setAdapter(adapter);
        spStates.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                USAStates d = states[position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), d.getStateAbrivation(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });




public class USAStates {
        private String _Statename;
        private String _StateAbrivation;

        public USAStates(String pStatename, String pStateAbrivation) {
            Statename(pStatename);
            StateAbrivation(pStateAbrivation);
        }
        public void Statename(String pStatename) {
            _Statename = pStatename;
        }
        public void StateAbrivation(String pStateAbrivation) {
            _StateAbrivation = pStateAbrivation;
        }

        public String getStatename() {
            return _Statename;
        }
        public String getStateAbrivation() {
            return _StateAbrivation;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, just doing this off the top of my head but, in your USAState class override your toString method.As is it maybe that the adapter is using the default toString() hence your weird text displaying (which I presume is the class name of the USAStates class)

for example

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return _Statename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally accepted the `toString()` answer but have since found that this doesn't appear to be right.

I had an ActionBar with spinner/drop down list and my adapter items were rendering with `String.toString()` value instead of of the title I set in the custom adapter. Adding `toString()` did fix initially until I tried to set a compound drawable in the same layout.

I needed to override `getDropDownView` as well as `getView`in my adapter.

Having to override `toString()` is symptomatic that you haven't overridden the right methods in your adapter.

When overriding getDropDownView having to override `toString()` is no longer required and everything works as expected.

And the answer on the following post is a great way to implement by using the super method:
[alternating colors of spinner items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447009/alternating-colors-of-spinner-items)